# What relation between 10 digits and datetime

Tags: python, math, logic

I search the relation between these times (in seconds) and these timestamps

```
30 seconds => 1189765120
1 minute => 1198153728
2 minutes => 1206542524
4 minutes => 1214930944
```

These info come from "Image Line FL Studio" music software.

I try to make a program in Python to manipulate FLP file, and I search without success the function for example:
`F(30) = 1189765120`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249182/discussion-on-question-by-julien-babrut-what-relation-between-10-digits-and-date).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this time I found the answer (the exponential progression 1/2, 1, 2, 4 minutes of your length, and the counting bits, and the 0 almost always gave me the hint: it looks like floating point representation)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(){
    uint32_t l[]={1189765120, 1198153728, 1206542524, 1214930944};
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%f\n", *(float *)(l+i));
    }
}
```

gives

```
30000.000000
60000.000000
120001.468750
240000.000000
```

So, what you have here, is just float32 representation of time in milliseconds. The information was there after all, and it was indeed a timestamp. With an extra milliseconds and some micro and nanoseconds in the 3rd case to make the reverse engineering harder.

Edit:
Since it is flagged python (tho it was more a math puzzle than a coding question) here is how you can do it in python (handling bits is more natural in C, but there is a package in python to do so)

```py
import struct
l=[1189765120, 1198153728, 1206542524, 1214930944]
for x in l:
    print(x, '=>', struct.unpack('f', struct.pack('I', x))[0])
```

2nd Edit: and only now I realize that your question was for F(30)=1189765120, not the other way round (I was too focused on the puzzle), well, it is just the reverse

```py
import struct
def F(sec):
    return struct.unpack('I', struct.pack('f', sec*1000))[0]
```

```
>>> F(30), F(60), F(120), F(240)
(1189765120, 1198153728, 1206542336, 1214930944)
```

Note the slight difference for `F(120)` from the number you gave. Explained by the extra microseconds

Comment: Awesome it works. I spend time to understand and you finally find the solution. Thank you very much !